# Python Plotly's Dash: How do you shut the web app running on a port or make changes to it? CTRL+C doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

Am using Plotly's Dash and trying to run the sample app code which they have provided here: https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started#dash-app-layout

Am having trouble with the ports. The code on being run shows this in the console: [image: the console image]

However , even after making changes to the code, the output in the web app shows no change.

Basically, when I'm implementing a different code: the web app continues to display the output from the previous run!

The CTRL+C doesn't seem to help and doesn't really quit or cause any change to the application. Please let me know what shall help.

I ran the new code using a new port(8049) and that worked but doesn't solve the initial basic issue!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issues, and find that a full restart of the app is necessary to get some changes to propagate in the app after a file update.

In POSIX, you could run `sudo killall python` or similar. Looks like you're running Windows, so taskmanager or `taskkill /F /IM python.exe`.

The `[1]:` Looks like a Jupyter kernel is running? If so, try restarting the kernel. [image]

Answer (score 0):

For me CTRL+C doesn't work either, but CTRL+Pause/Break button stops execution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I came here today as I'm newly trying out Plotly+Dash. I add this to help anyone here in 2023!

For current Dash (v2.7.0) there is no need to kill the terminal from which the Dash `app.py` was launched. Changes to the `app.py` file (once saved) are automatically incorporated into the hosted HTML page, which refreshes every few seconds.

In VS Code, it is possible to kill the terminal and then relaunch the `app.py` file, but as stated above, it is not necessary for the Dash App to incorporate saved changes to that file.

(Tested with Dash v2.7.0, VS Code 1.80.1 and Chrome browser)